# Identity insert when adding many to many relations EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i made a many to many relationship and the table was created with Classes and Users for a gym web app,but when i try to insert values to that table i get **SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'classes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.**

My models are
Class

```
 public class Class
        {
            [Key]
            public int ClassID { get; set; }
            ...
            public List<UserClass> userClasses { get; set; }
      }
```

User:

```
public class User
        {
            [Key]
            public int UserID{ get; set; }
            ...
            public List<UserClass> userClasses { get; set; }
      }
```

Where they merge:

```
public class UserClass
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long UserClassID { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int ClassID { get; set; }

        public User user { get; set; }
        public Class @class { get; set; }
    }
```

my context class modelbiulder function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserClass>()
               .HasKey(x => new { x.UserID, x.ClassID });

            //If you name your foreign keys correctly, then you don't need this.
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserClass>()
                .HasOne(uc => uc.user)
                .WithMany(p => p.userClasses)
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserClass>()
                .HasOne(uc => uc.@class)
                .WithMany(t => t.userClasses)
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.ClassID);
        }
```

and this function that i use with ajax

```
public IActionResult BookTheClass(int ClassID)
        {
            User user = _context.users.Find(_auth.User.UserID);
            Class selectedClass = _context.classes.Find(ClassID);

            selectedClass.userClasses = new List<UserClass>() {
                    new UserClass{
                   user=user,
                    @class=selectedClass
                    }
            };
            _context.classes.Add(selectedClass);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return PartialView("~/Views/PartialViews/ClassBooked.cshtml");
        }
```

The other similar questions had a model builder problem that i dont have.

Answer (score 0):

An identity column will keep track of the next free number, and you do not need to generate the ClassId by yourself. The new id can be fetched by `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

If you really want to insert value to an identity column(*not recommended*) then you would have to switch on the `Identity Insert` property of your table. See the below SQL to do the same

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT classes ON
```

Comment: If you are ready to remove SaveChanges, then why not remove `_context.classes.Add(selectedClass);` as well. In fact why are you adding an object in your classes DbSet if you are not going to sync it with your DB?

Comment: sorry typo meant that removing _context.classes.Add(selectedClass); solves the problems since i dont add anything i update them